# Order entries based on last string of title

Tags: entries, entry, order, set

I would like to get the last string of a entry title and order entries based on that. Basically the `people` title are their full names and I am trying to find their last name and filter based on that, instead of their first name.

`{% set entries = craft.entries.section('people').order('title').limit(0) %}`

similar to this `entry.title|split(' ')|last`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It’s not possible to do that unless you’ve already got the last word saved somewhere.

Here’s what I would recommend:

- Create two new Plain Text fields - “First Name” and “Last Name”
- Go to your People section’s entry type settings
- Uncheck the “Show the Title field?” setting and set the “Title Format” setting to:

  ```
  {firstName} {lastName}
  ```
- Add the “First Name” and “Last Name” fields to the entry type’s field layout
- Save the entry type
- Update your existing People entries

With those changes made, you will now be able to order directly by your Last Name field’s values:

```
{% set entries = craft.entries.section('people').order('lastName asc').limit(0) %}
```

Comment: Oh ok, ya unfortunately these titles we're imported from wordpress so the title tags were already populated and we have 122 `people` so redoing them all is too big of a task. Thanks anyway!

Comment: @KenyonKowal Gotcha. Just added a new answer that should work for you.

Answer (score 4):

Another option is to use the [Preparse](https://github.com/aelvan/Preparse-Field-Craft) plugin to automatically parse out and store last names in a hidden field.

- Install the Preparse plugin
- Create a new “Last Name” field using the Preparse field type
- Set the field’s Twig template setting to this:

  ```
  {{ entry.title|split(' ')|last }}
  ```
- Edit the People section’s entry type settings, and add the Last Name field to its field layout.
- Edit the People section’s main settings - just re-save them, so that all of your existing entries get updated.

Now when your People entries are saved, the last word in their Title will be copied over to a hidden “Last Name” field, and you can sort by that in your template:

```
{% set entries = craft.entries.section('people').order('lastName asc').limit(0) %}
```